# Importing projects from multiple git repositories into single eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, git

From Git Repositories view of Eclipse it is possible to select a repository right click and select "Import Projects..." to import a project from a single git repository.
But if I select multiple repositories and right click there is no "Import Projects..." option.

I have multiple git repositories, I want to import projects from these repositories into a single eclipse workspace. Is there any plugin which allows to select multiple repositories and import projects into current workspace.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the repositories and import projects from one repository at once.
The previous projects will sill be available in that workspace.

Comment: @Pusker György I have added these repositories for the first time. Projects will not be available in workspace unless imported.

Comment: seems like i misunderstood the problem.
I don't see what's the issue, you can import the projects one by one.
So is it working for you this way and you just looking for a better solution or do you have some porblem importing the projects?

Comment: @@Pusker György There is no issue in importing project one by one. But in my organization we have more than 100 repositories and to run a service we need to import projects from at least 50 repositories. I am looking for a solution which can import projects into workspace in one go instead of doing it one by one.

Comment: Oh, I see now what§s the problem is, I can't help with that sorry!